# pasting files/multiple columns with different number of rows

Tags: awk, paste

Hi I was trying to paste multiple files (each with a single column but different number of rows) together. But it did't provide what I was expecting. How to solve that?

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt paste3.txt ... paste100 > out.txt
```

input file 1:

```
A
B
C
```

input file 2:

```
D
E
```

input file 3:

```
F
G
H
I
J
```

.......
......

Desired output:

```
A   D   F
B   E   G
C       H
        I
        J
```

Would this be same if the files have multiple columns with different number of rows?
for example:

file1

```
A  1
B  2
C  3
```

file2

```
D  4
E  5
```

file3

```
F  6  %
G  7  &
H  8  #
I  9  @
J  10 ?
```

output:

```
A  1  D  4  F  6  %
B  2  E  5  G  7  &
C  3        H  8  #
            I  9  @
            J  10 ?
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the default behaviour of `paste` exactly what you ask?

```
% paste <(echo "a
b
c
d") <(echo "1
2
3") <(echo "10
> 20
> 30
> 40
> 50
> 60")
a       1       10
b       2       20
c       3       30
d               40
                50
                60
%
```

Comment: You are right. After pasting i did a "cut -f1" and I noticed that it does show A  1  B   2  C  3  but also some empty rows up to level of file 3 (2 more empty rows to match number of total rows 5). how to solve that?

Comment: I've given the correct answer, or so it seems from your words, to your question. Now you have another question, so please ask another question.